# Override Scala Panel Coordinates

Tags: scala, overriding, panel, scala-2.8, scala-collections

I am attempting to override the coordinate system of a scala.swing.Panel.  I want to work only in the first quadrant on the Cartesian coordinate system.   Thus, I want the lower left hand corner of the panel to be noted as (0,0), and therefore the mouse will register as only positive x and y values when moving across the panel.  Does anyone know if this is possible??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to translate the co-ordinates so that the bottom-left is the origin rather than the top-right, do this:

```
  case e: MouseClicked => {
    val newPoint = new Point(e.point.x, size.height - e.point.y)
    // do stuff using newPoint instead of e.point
  }
```

I don't think you really want to override the whole co-ordinate system, as it would likely play havoc with painting and alligning the component.

Another thing you could do would be to override the `getMousePosition` method of the underlying JPanel:

```
  val p = new Panel { 
    override lazy val peer = new javax.swing.JPanel with SuperMixin {
      override def getMousePosition = {
        val p: Point = super.getMousePosition
        new Point(p.x, getHeight - p.y)
      }
    }
  ...
```

Then

```
  case e: MouseClicked => {
    val newPoint: Point = peer.getMousePosition
    // do stuff
  }
```

However, overriding `getMousePosition` doesn't affect the reported position on the `MouseClicked` event, so doesn't gain much over the first way.

Comment: Thanks, the new point method is a great solution to this problem!